# Format Exception was Unhandled error

Tags: c#, string, exception, unhandled

I am getting a weird error on run that I can't figure out. When I am in Visual Studio no error is thrown until I run the program. When I run it however I get an error saying that there was an unhandled exception on type. This is pertaining to the conversion of the field[0] to an int, any advice?

```
empReader = new StreamReader(fileName);

                while (empReader.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    string line = empReader.ReadLine();   //read a line from the text file
                    string[] fields = line.Split(',');

                    int idCheck = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);

                    empTempId.Add(idCheck);
                }

                empReader.Close();
```

Comment: Several problems: 1) What's "fields[0]" (is it a valid format(, and 2) Does "fields[0]" even *EXIST*?

Comment: Nevertheless, the code assumes that whatever "ReadLine()" returns, it will be a string that can be split() into at least one comma-delimited element.  And That's Bad...

Answer (score 1):

If you're unsure whether or not the value will be an integer, use `int.TryParse` instead:

```
int idCheck;

if (int.TryParse(fields[0], out idCheck))
    empTempId.Add(idCheck);
```

This prevents a runtime exception by trying to convert, then returning `false` if it cannot do so.

Comment: You can wrap it in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a try/catch block.

```
try {
         int idCheck = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", fields[0], idCheck);
     }
catch (FormatException) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Bad Format", fields[0]);
     }   
catch (OverflowException) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Overflow", fields[0]);   
     }
```